# Trap Ctrl+C and repeat the while loop in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I was trying to trap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> and clear the screen and repeat the loop without exiting – it's working but I need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to repeat the loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'clear' 2 20
while :
do
        clear
        echo -e "\n\t1. Create a user"
        echo -e "\t2. Create a Group"
        echo -e "\t3. Delete user"
        echo -e "\t4. Reset Password"
        echo -e "\n\tSelect one of the option : \c"
        read OPT
done
```

When pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> it clears the screen but does not display the menu again.

I want to use this as a logon script where a user logs in and only gets this menu to work. If the user enters <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> the script has to redisplay the menu, without coming to shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'menu' 2 20

menu()
{
   clear
   echo -e "\n\t1. Create a user"
   echo -e "\t2. Create a Group"
   echo -e "\t3. Delete user"
   echo -e "\t4. Reset Password"
   echo -e "\n\tSelect one of the option : \c"
}

while :; do
   menu
   read OPT
done
```

If you don't want to have to press the Enter key to repeat the loop, change the read command to:

```
read -n 1 OPT
```